# how do you use Wp-cli on Shared Hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting, wp-cli

I Have Godaddy Deluxe linux hosting it is shared server, so I don’t have the root password of the machine.

I can create, move and delete files via SSH in my home folder but not in the root directories like /opt /etc.

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar

php wp-cli.phar --info

chmod +x wp-cli.phar

sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

I am not able to execute the `sudo` command.

Can anyone gives me alternate way for installing it?

Comment: You probably better ask the wp-cli developers. You can't sudo if you don't have server root like privileges which you will not get on shared hosting, but I don't understand why that step is needed at all.

Comment: these commands are from the official documentations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default instructions assume you have root and are intended to provide the most convenient use by placing the phar package in your path

alternative 1:

remove the sudo, change `/usr/local/bin/wp` to `/path/to/your/installation/wp`, and instead of calling the commands with `wp command <parameters>` use `./wp command <parameters>`

alternative 2:

remove the sude, change `/usr/local/bin/wp` to `/any/other/path/wp` and instead of calling commands with `wp command <parameters>` use `/any/other/path/wp command <parameters>`

Comment: if word-press installed in public_html/folder so i have to put wp-cli.phar in same folder.
and whenever i have to perform wp-cli command... i have to type ./wp command <parameters> ?

Comment: you would need to rename wp-cli.phar to just wp, but yes that's one of the methods